# Should I stop my dog from attempting to defecate more than needed?

Tags: dogs, defecation

When I simply let my dog out to use the bathroom, she will always go normally without issue.

The problem I am concerned about happens when we go on longer walks of about 2 mi. (3.2km).  She stops *constantly* to try and poop.  The first two to three times everything is normal and I have something to bag up...  But she continues to try to go many more times after she has nothing left in her system.  This will usually cause a mucus-like substance to excrete and it looks very unhealthy.  On top of my health concerns, it can also be embarrassing for me to have my dog do the motions of going #2, and then I walk away without picking anything up - as she didn't actually go.  My dog has done this on walks for the 7-8 years I have had her.

Once my dog's system is empty, should I hurry her along on my walk or allow her to try multiple times to go... when she can't?

Comment: Sounds like something that's worth discussing with a vet IMO

Comment: The excretion may be the natural excretion from the dog's anal glands that normally is excreted when the dog defecates, but I still agree the dog should be taken to the vet.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this is something she has done for as long as I remember, not something new.  I didn't really think much about it until a friend I was walking with started a conversation about it.  My dog also seems very healthy (other than this) and she sees a vet regularly.  I will still bring it up on her next vet visit though.

Comment: My family dog has always done this, she’s 10 now, and it’s never affected her health. She just feels the need to go when she’s excited. (This is a known reaction in some humans, too, humans are just a little more controlled.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and what I do that seems to work is that after the poo bags finish (I usually take 2-3),  I keep my dog closer to me by adjusting where I hold the leash from. This way I drive the dog and the dog doesn't drive me and it is more difficult for him to find a place that he wants to poo.

It seems that this way the dog doesn't feel very comfortable to defecate and continues his walk with you without trying to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should consult a vet about any possible digestive concerns or other health problems, but if all is well and it's just an odd habit, distracting her by keeping her moving briskly along once she's done her business is probably the way to go.  Dogs need both leisurely 'sniff around and pee on stuff' walk time, and 'lets put some miles behind us' walk time. The exercise and sense of travel/motion is good for them physically and mentally.